# Regex to match a maximum of 6 digits which may include 1 dash or 1 space anywhere between the digits?

Tags: regex

I need help with this:

```
\d{1,5}(-| )\d{1,5}
```

This is what I'm working on:

```
^([C][A|F|G|J|K|L])( |)(\d{1,6}|\d{1,5}(-| )\d{1,5})$
```

`([C][A|F|G|J|K|L])` matches the first 2 characters.

`( |)` matches an optional space.

`\d{1,6}` matches 1-6 digits without any dash or space.

`\d{1,5}(-| )\d{1,5}` is supposed to match a 2-6 digit number which includes either 1 dash or 1 space.

I need help with the last part, but if you know a better way to write the entire Regex, then it should only start with a `'C'` and the second character should only be either `'A'`, `'F'`, `'G'`, `'J'`, `'K'` or `'L'`. After the first 2 characters, there can optionally be a `' '` (space) character, followed by the 1-6 digits.

Here are examples of what I want to match for the entire Regex:

```
CA 123456
CF 1
CK 0467 21
CL 4 2
CG 456-789
CJ 1-23
```

And, if possible (optional), it should also match:

```
CA546
CJ99-0
CK8 0565
```

It should NOT match:

```
CZ 123456
C 987-123
CA 12345-
CK  12
CJ -456
CL-654
CJ 1234567
```

Comment: I think it may be because the title of my question didn't match the very beginning of my description. I edited it after the downvote to better express the fact that I need help with a specific part of the regular expression and not the entire expression. The refactoring of the entire expression was optional, so I appreciate that you've given the full expression with explanation. It would come in handy if I have to make small changes later.

Comment: I second you both, I very much enjoyed your question and learned a lot! Thanks for such a well written and solvable question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your regex to this,

```
^C[AFGJKL] ?(?=(?:\d+[ -]\d+$|\d{1,6}$))[\d -]{1,7}$
```

and achieve your [Desired Results](https://regex101.com/r/sDSMGO/1)

You don't need `|` when you place characters in a character set `[]` and single character `[C]` can simply be written as `C`

Writing an optional character can be done by any character followed by a `?` so optional space can be written as  `?`

Only tricky part is how do you write `\d{1,5}(-| )\d{1,5}` in a way so that it either matches only 1 to 6 digits or if there is a single space or hyphen between the digits, then it should match one more additional character to incorporate that space or hyphen so max matched characters become 7 instead of 6, which is where I will explain following regex part,

```
(?=(?:\d+[ -]\d+$|\d{1,6}$))[\d -]{1,7}
```

- `(?=` - positive lookahead so that either of `\d+[ -]\d+$` or `\d{1,6}$` should match, which essentially says, either match (`\d+[ -]\d+$`) one or more digits separated with a space or hyphen and again one or more digits else just (`\d{1,6}$`) match 1 to 6 digits
- `[\d -]{1,7}` - Finally just capture digits space and hyphen

Comment: This looks like the best and most elegant solution! I just have one question about the non-capturing group: does it work in a way, that you kind of 'probe' the string with a regex without consuming it, so that the following part ```[\d -]{1,7}``` can properly match it? And the probe acts like a guard, so that multiple regex can be applied to the string?

Comment: `?:` non capturing group basically doesn't store the matched data in group1 as its not needed, else it doesn't have any other impact. The kind of probe is actually done by that `(?=` positive lookahead which doesn't match/capture any characters, just tries to validate the format you specify after that and matching pointer is reset back to original position after lookahead ends.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I think I understand. As the result is the same, does the non-capturing group has some performance advantages, or why would it be better to use it in this case?

Comment: The performance impact which should also be quite minimal should be the storage part only. Its like if you want to store something, then you need a place holder or memory vs not storing anything, you don't even need that placeholder so that should only be the difference. Imagine a complex regex which has lot of groups would consume even more memory vs not storing any of the group memory would use lesser memory.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single lookahead making sure that there are not 7 consecutive digits.

Then match 1+ digits followed by an optional part matching either a space or `-` and then again 1+ digits.

Or make it more specific, matching `\d{1,5}` digits as specified in the question

```
^C[AFGJKL](?! ?\d{7}) ?\d+(?:[ -]\d+)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `C` Match literally
- `[AFGJKL]` Match one of the listed characters
- `(?! ?\d{7})` Negative lookahead, assert not an optional space followed by 7 consecutive digits
- `?` Match an optional space
- `\d+(?:[ -]\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional part matching either a space or `-` followed by 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8YcWXF/1).

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but I think regex doesn't provide a functionality to define a maximum length, and at the same time limit the occurrence of a specific char. Thus, you need to match all possible cases.

```
^(C[AFGJKL]) ?(\d{1,6}|\d{1,5}[- ]\d|\d{1,4}[- ]\d{1,2}|\d{1,3}[- ]\d{1,3}|\d{1,2}[- ]\d{1,4}|\d[- ]\d{1,5})$
```

[regex101-link](https://regex101.com/r/j22i82/1)

**some further improvements:**

- in order to make a matcher optional, you can use `x?`, which makes the matcher or the group before optional
- when you want to match a char of a set of chars, you can just create a new character class. `[asdf]` would match any of the letters 'a', 's', 'd', 'f'.